# mongodb typescript type checking

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

In node I am using mongodb client and the findMany query returns an Array of Documents.

What I actually need is that I should be able to make sure if the returned Array contains all the fields which a return type expecting.

I have defined a type e.g Game like

```
export type Game {
 name: string;
 description: string;
 ...
}
```

and my query looks like

```
const  games = (await this.games.find({}).toArray()) as Game[];
```

But I did not find any mechanism to be sure if the response contains all the fields which `Game` type requires.

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that the documents on the returned array have all the fields using `$exists`.

```js
const games = (await this.games.find({field1: {$exists: true}, field2: {$exists: true}}).toArray()) as Game[];
```

or make it dinamic with the keys of Game.